# Need to convert a dump.sql to a *fname.dump file for restoration of Odoo

Tags: postgresql, psql, odoo-13

My last working database back up of an Odoo13CE system was a full one, including the file store. I'm getting timeouts when trying to restore "a copy" via Odoo database manager page. Thought I could just do a partial restore (dump.sql & manifest.json), dump the filestore, recompress and upload and that brought everything down to its knees (Errored w/" no *.dump file found). So logged into server and dropped my failed restore and restarted odoo service and all is back to somewhat normal, with the database I want to replace active.

Is there a way to convert that .sql to a .dump or some other way to get my .sql to be added to my pgdb? I'm fairly green re: psql so if I'm missing something simple, please feel free to shove it down my throat.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

to restore sql back up file to a new database:

```
psql YOUR_DATABASE_NAME < YOUR_FILENAME
```

You can read more about restoring/back up Postgres Db here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/backup-dump.html

Answer (score 0):

1. **Restoring** the heavy size `database`(`with file store`) you have to increase the **limit** of the server to continue your process.

Add the **parameter** on your path

> --limit-time-cpu=6000 --limit-time-real=12000

2. **Restore** the **SQL** File

> psql database_name < your_file.sql

3. **Restore** the **Dump** File

> pg_restore -d database_name < your_file.dump